# Exist rule fails on null value even if coupled with nullable rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6 in my current project. In a Request object's rules I have the following rules function:

```
public function rules()
{
    if ($this->input('preset') === self::NO_PRESET) {
        $this->merge(['preset' => null]);
    }
    return [
        'preset' => 'nullable|exists:roles_presets,id',
        ...
    ];
}
```

However, when 'preset' is null, the rule for `exists:roles_presets,id` still fails. Shouldn't it not be reached because the field is null and such a value is permitted by the `nullable` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the merge inside the `rules` function, override the `validationData` and add your logic there.

```
public function validationData()
{
    if ($this->input('preset') === self::NO_PRESET) {
        $this->merge(['preset' => null]);
    }

    // returns $this->all();
    return parent::validationData();
}
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea. It's weird that it works with the data change in an other function. Do you know why?

Comment: It's about timing, the rules function is called too late and not every time, the validationData function is called everytime you are checking if the request is valid. I had to look at the source of the base request class